# Dataflow job fails, but the step still shows successful

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Our pipeline failed, but the graph in the developers console still shows it as been successful. However, the results were **not** written to BigQuery, and the job log clearly shows it failed.

Shouldn't the graph show it as failed too?
[image]

Another example:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for catching this polleyg -- we'll take a look at this issue.

Comment: this is still an issue for us. See new screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug with the handling of BigQuery outputs that was fixed in a release of the Dataflow service.  Thank you for your patience.